# Issue in accessing Nextcloud using DDNS

Tags: ubuntu, dns, router, portforwarding, nextcloud

I have installed NextCloud in an Ubuntu 17 VM on ESXi 6.5 (IP eg. 192.168.1.30) and configured the router with DDNS Hostname and port forwarding with Port 80->80, 8888->443 and 443->443.
I purchased a domain name (say xyz.com) and created a CNAME record with nextcloud.xyz.com poining to DDNS hostname (abc.ddns.com).

Now when I resolve nextcloud.xyz.com from any network using nslookup it gives me correct Dynamic Public IP configured on my router, it means domain forwarding to DDNS hostname is working.
But web portal (eg. http://nextcloud.xyz.com) only works with LAN, when I tried to open from different network it gives timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled and found that many ISPs generally block the http port 80. So I create a NAT Port forwarding rule from External Port 8888 (NextCloud Port) to Internal Port 80. and Boom.. Issue resolved. Now I am able to open my Nextcloud web portal/Next Cloud App using http://:8888.